# How to scrape text from <div><ul><li><a>?

Tags: ruby, web-scraping

I want to scrape this website https://www.bananatic.com/es/forum/games/. I need to extract the games located in the "Games" table. [image: https://www.bananatic.com/es/forum/games/]
As you can see, this is inside a "scrollArea" div, then there is a `<ul>` inside a `<li>`, then an `<a>` and a `<span>` I need to save the text of `<a>` in a variable and the number which is in `<span>` in another variable.  That, for example, show me on the console:

### Roblox

### 146

### BigFarm

### 135...etc

[image]
This is my bad code, not working correctly:

```
`require 'nokogiri'
require 'csv'
require 'open-uri'

link = 'https://www.bananatic.com/es/forum/games/'
pagina = URI.open(link)
datos = pagina.read
documento = Nokogiri::HTML(datos)
#p =     documento.css('.container').css('.categories').css('.scrollArea')
r = documento.css('.categories')
# print r
result = r.css('div.scrollArea > ul > li').each do |li|
   name = li.css('span').text.strip
   print name

  number = li.css('a').text.strip
  print number
end`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link node contains two child nodes, even though the name is not contained within a separate element (unlike the count, which is inside the *span*).

```
require "nokogiri"
require 'open-uri'
# download/cache the data (to speed up testing)
if !File.readable?("data.html")
  url = "https://www.bananatic.com/de/forum/games/"
  data = URI.open(url).read
  File.open("data.html", "wb") { |f| f << data }
end

data = File.read("data.html")
document = Nokogiri::HTML(data)
links = document.css(".categories ul li a")
result = links.map do |link|
  name, count = link.children
  [name.text.strip, count.text.to_i]
end

p result
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to read the data by tweaking your code as below:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

link = 'https://www.bananatic.com/es/forum/games/'
pagina = URI.open(link)
datos = pagina.read
documento = Nokogiri::HTML(datos)
game_data = []
r = documento.css('div.categories')
result = r.css('div.scrollArea > ul > li').each do |li|
  game_data << {
    name:   li.child.children.first.text.strip,
    number: li.child.children.last.text.strip
  }
end

puts game_data
```

The `li` node had 2 children nodes with a child node.
I have set all the data into a separate variable as `game_data` which is a collection of all the game data that you can print or use as per your requirement.

Hope this helps you understand the issue within the provided code.